# Is there a way to use the find function to identify a column with value only of a specific length?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to make a macro which asks the user to select an excel file, then goes through each column (without headers), identifies the column who values have a length of only 7 and copy it into the original excel where the macro is.

```
Sub Upload()

InitializeSettings

Dim FindOrdernummer As Range
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls; *.xlsx), *.xls; *.xlsx", , "Browse for your File & Import")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
  Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
  OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:Z70").Find
End If


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I am thinking of making a for loop but i am unable to code the part where it looks through the entire column and not just a particular cell.

Help would be much appreciated on this seemingly simple matter!

Comment: Do you mean that every cell in the column needs to have a value of 7 characters? Or do you need to copy the column if at least one of the cells in the column has 7 characters?

Comment: I mean that every cell in the columns needs to have a value of 7 characters. If this condition is satisfied, then i would like to copy this into the workbook where macro is.

Answer (score 0):

This Loop should list all the Value that length is 7.

```
        Option Explicit
        Dim MacroWb As Workbook
        
        Sub Upload()
        
        InitializeSettings
        
        Dim FindOrdernummer As Range
        Dim FileToOpen As Variant
        Dim OpenBook As Workbook
        
        Set MacroWb = ThisWorkbook
        
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls; *.xlsx), *.xls; *.xlsx", , "Browse for your File & Import")
        If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        Call FindValuesWithlengtOfSeven
        End If
        
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End Sub
        
        Sub FindValuesWithlengtOfSeven()
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim cel As Range
        Dim Occurrence As Long
        
        Occurrence = 1
        
        Set rng = OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:Z70")
        
        For Each cel In rng
            If Len(cel.Value) = 7 Then
        '********** Change it to the sheet name you want to put the list "TheNameOfTheSheet"
                MacroWb.Sheets("TheNameOfTheSheet").Range("A" & Occurrence).Value = cel.Value
                Occurrence = Occurrence + 1
            End If
        Next cel
        
        Set rng = Nothing
        
        End Sub
```

Comment: Can you tell why option explicit HAS to be on top of the module?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But it isnt what i was looking for. Your code copies all the cells with a length of 7. What I want is some code to copy only a specific column's values if all of its lengths are 7. And then paste it into a specific range into my original workbook.(for example from P3 onwards below)

Comment: Option Explicit
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't select all cells at once that have a value with a length of 7, so you need to go through all the cells in the column to check.

You can do that with a for loop and it would look something like this:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim col As Range
Dim ws As worksheet

Set worksheet = Application.ActiveSheet
Set r = ws.Range("A1:Z70")

For Each col In r.Columns
    Dim copyColumn As Boolean
    copyColumn = True 'make sure you reset this variable for every column
    
    For i = 1 To 70
        If Len(ws.Cells(i, col.Column).Value) <> 7 Then
            copyColumn = False
            Exit For
            'If one of the cells does not have a value with a length of 7,
            'you can stop the loop and continue to the next column
        Next
    Next i
    
    If copyColumn = True Then
        'Copy the column
    End If

Next col
```